Name of the novel about something turning people's pupils into triangles
I never read the book, but I remember seeing the cover and looking it up several years ago, but I have forgotten the title.
All I remember about it is that the cover shows an human eye with a triangular pupil and that something was turning people aggressive(I think), probably aliens, and it also turned there eyes triangular. I think it also involves a football player, maybe as MC.
I do not remember more sadly. Maybe this rings some bells for you guys.

This question is a dupe of Alien invasion story involving satellite trying to build a portal.

Oh, well...I already got my answer, lol!!! @fez

This sounds very much like Scott Sigler's Infected.

Perry Dawsey is 6-foot-5, 265 pounds of andry ex-linebacker. He knows all too well that if he doesn't control his quick temper, people get hurt. Through constant focus, he has locked his violent past away in the deep dungeons of his mind.
The infection changes everything.
Strange microscopic parasites tap into Perry's bloodstream like tiny
little vampires. They start as bright orange blisters, but soon take
the shape of triangular growths just beneath his skin. The
"Triangles," as Perry calls them, try to control their host by
manipulating hormone levels and flooding his body with
neurotransmitters -- imbalances of which cause paranoia, schizophrenia
and excessive aggression. As Perry begins a desperate battle to cut
the Triangles out of his body before it's too late, his self-control
dissolves into raging, murderous madness.

Cover:


100% it, thanks!!!
